# How to recover from a packet_write_wait: broken pipe error on AWS EC2?

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

When I connect to my AWS Ubuntu instance from my MacOS Sierra terminal, I get booted within a few minutes with the following error:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 52.152.221.18 port 22: Broken pipe
```

I set up the AWS Ubuntu server using all the default settings. I've read the other posts relating to the getting booted issue--which I'm confident I can figure out. However, my problem is that I cannot reconnect to the AWS instance once I get booted. The following is the error and the failed ssh commands trying to reconnect. How should I rectify this situation?

```
ubuntu@ip-171-31-50-30:~/scripts$ packet_write_wait: Connection to 52.152.221.18 port 22: Broken pipe
jk-MacBook-Pro:credentials jk$ ssh -i ubuntu-server-12-18-2016.pem ubuntu@ec2-52-152-221-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-52-152-221-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
jk-MacBook-Pro:credentials jk$ ssh -i ubuntu-server-12-18-2016.pem ubuntu@ec2-52-152-221-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-52-152-221-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
jk-MacBook-Pro:credentials jk$
```